# Define several classes @Deprecated at once

Tags: java, eclipse, deprecated

Is there an Eclipse plugin to add `@Deprecated` annotion several classes at once ?

Indeed, I have dozens of class to depreciate, and I do not want to do one at a time: p

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23019294/174184

Comment: Just add @Deprecated tho the base one

Comment: @TJ- I'm using JDK 6 and it does not seem to work :( ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the classes are all in the same package (or subpackages of one package) you can use a simple search-and-replace. Select the package, click the Search toolbar button (its icon is a flashlight). In the Search dialog select the File Search tab and enter `public class` as the text to search for, `*.java` as the **File name pattern**, and **Selected resources** as the **Scope**. Then click the **Replace...** button. Enter `@Deprecated public class` as the replacement text.

You can use other choices for **Scope** to change the scope of your search/replace - one powerful option is to use a Working Set, but it takes a little work to define one.