# How to deprecate a package in android

Tags: java, android, package, deprecated

In my android project (Windows 7, Android Studio 2.2.3 with java 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64, gradle 2.14.1) I tried to deprecate one of my packages using the package-info.java file (as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23019294) like this:

```
/**
 * @deprecated As of 22.02.2017 
 */
@Deprecated
package com.x.y;
```

But got the following compilation error:

> PathtoProject\app\src\main\java\com\x\y\package-info.java:5:error: modifier deprecated not allowed here
>   package com.x.y;

Why is this error ocurring? And what's the correct way to make a package deprecated?
Somebody else seemed to have had this problem as well and it didn't get resolved:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233212

Answer (score 1):

- Package cannot be deprecated only classes can be deprecated see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html).
- Also according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html),  packages are meant for managing the classes in an organised way and also to avoid class name collisions.
- So instead of annotating a package with `@Deprecated` annotate all public classes of the with `@Deprecated`