# Deprecating an entire package in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jvm, deprecated

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23019294/1076585) package-level deprecation is possible in Java via `package-info.java` like so:

```
/**
 * @deprecated As of release 2.0, replaced by {@link com.acme.new.package}
 */
@Deprecated
package com.acme.old.package;
```

Is there something similar to this mechanism in Kotlin? The [Deprecated](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecated/) page documentation doesn't seem to offer guidance on this and I'd prefer not to annotate every function, field, and class separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same `package-info.java`; Kotlin should recognize the deprecations specified in it, and if it doesn't, it's a bug. Kotlin has no syntax of its own for specifying package-level annotations.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, although I wish there was a way to do this that allowed me to put KDoc alongside the deprecation.